# missing Apache Tomcat Native library and page can't be displayed

Tags: java-8, tomcat8

While trying to run a java program in tomcat in linux machine and accessing the url it is showing "page cant't be displayed".When I checked the log file I got to see this info:"

> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent

The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:

> [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]"

. Is this the reason why I am unable to access the application pls help me.

Comment: AS you can read int the documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/apr.html and http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html, the APR is optional. If it's missing Tomcat will use one of the pure Java connectors instead.

Comment: okay then what might be the reason that I am not able to access the application what might be the reason it is showing "Page can't be displayed". There are no other errors recorded in the log file.

Comment: I cannot answer that without details about the application: how it works, what it does, how it is deployed and so on. Also which log file are you talking about: catalina.out, catalina.log, localhost.log, some other log?

Comment: this java appl was developed in java 1.5 previuosly. But now it needs to run in a linux server wer java 1.8 &tomcat 8.5 installed. In my windows machine eclipse I did an ant build of this appl and placed the war files in linux machine & thro command run in putty i started the tomcat and tried to access the appli path and it showed "Page Can't be displayed".The above log file is catalina.log

Comment: What JDK version did you use to build the application? Also catalina.log shoud have line 'Deployment of web application archive path/to/application.war' inside and below should be the application's startup logs. Are there any errors there?

Comment: I used JDK 1.8 version only....there are no errors in the log file